# Biharmonic equation in oblate spheroidal coordinates

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

What is the solution of the biharmonic equation
\begin{equation}
 \nabla^2\nabla^2 f=0
\end{equation}
in [oblate spheroidal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroidal_coordinates)?

The general solution of Laplace's equation $\nabla^2 f=0$ in oblate spheroidal coordinates is known as an [oblate spheroidal harmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblate_spheroidal_coordinates). According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation) any solution of Laplace equation is also a solution of biharmonic equation, but the vice versa is not always true. Therefore I assume there exists a more general solution of the biharmonic equation.

Comment: @doraemonpaul: Please stop flooding the frontpage with many edits on the same day. If you continue, limit yourself to only a few per day please.

Answer (score 0):

Write the solution in terms of $f = \Xi_{\ell,m}(\xi)P_{\ell,m}(\eta)e^{i\phi}$ and plug into the biharmonic equation. You will obtain a differential equation for $\Xi_{\ell,m}$ with two regular and two irregular solutions based on $\xi$. In each class of solution is a spheroidal harmonic and the other is the product of a spheroidal harmonics (since a harmonic function is a solution of a biharmonic equation too) and a spheroidal harmonic times a function of $\xi$.